# Get a value even if one condition is false

Tags: sql, where-clause, exists

Here is my actual query :

```
SELECT temp.id_company AS id_company
     , temp.code_product AS id_product
     , temp.date_product  AS date_p
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM companies 
   INNER JOIN products
      ON products.id_company_product = companies.id_company
   WHERE module_key_company = "daL/RqzZcfqc."
   ) AS temp
WHERE temp.code_product = "app_12"
```

First i get the `companies.id_company where companies.module_key_company` match "dal....." then i check if i get a match for `products.code_product = "app_12"` AND `products.id_company = companies.id_company` i got after the first test.

If both conditions are true, i get what i want. But i also want to get the companies.id_company if there is no match for the `products.code_product`.

I can't find how i could get the id_company only with the `module_key` test even if the `code_product` is wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It sounds as though you want a left or right `outer join`, such that rows in the Companies table which lack matches in Products will still be output.

Comment: i don't get it...You mean make only one SELECT with both condition but just with LEFT join  instead of INNER ?

Comment: See this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join) about outer joins. Essentially, even if the ON condition for the join cannot be satisfied, one of the tables will still have all of its information output, while some rows of the output may contain NULL values for the unmatched conditions.

Comment: Ok i think i get it and it will not work for me. Because i'm sure i'll get a match on the module_key and so get an id_company. But in some case i'll not get match for the code_product on the got id_company. Sorry if i expose badly, i need sleep...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT companies.id_company
     , coalese(products.code_product,'NONE') as id_product
     , products.date_product as date_p
FROM companies 
LEFT OUTER JOIN products
   ON     products.id_company_product = companies.id_company
      and products.code_product = 'app_12'

WHERE companies.module_key_company = 'daL/RqzZcfqc.'
```

The `id_product` column will contain the text **NONE** and the `date_p` column will be **null** for companies that do not have any matching products.  Also, you should use single-quotes to provide character constants, not double-quotes.

Comment: Ok it works perfectly, i didn't knew that it was possible to put this kind of condition in a ON clause...Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what your table structure is, unless you are suffixing column names with table names.  So that is what I am guessing.  Try this:

```
SELECT C.id_company, P.code_product, P.date_product
  FROM Companies AS C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Products AS P ON P.id_company_product = C.id_company
  WHERE module_key_company = 'daL/RqzZcfqc.'
    AND (P.code_product = 'app_12' OR P.code_product is NULL)
```

Best,
Joe